# Find the missing digit

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$(172195)(572167)=985242x6565$

Obviously the answer is 9 if you have a calculator, but how can you find x without redoing the multiplication?

The book says to use congruences, but I don't see how that is very helpful.

Comment: Try modulo $11$

Comment: But 98524296565 isn't divisible by 11

Comment: It doesn't have to be divisible by 11 to go modulo 11.

Comment: Or modulo 9....

Comment: Modulo 9 gives 9 or 0 with no way to differentiate

Comment: And why I said "try modulo 11" 

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: So you did. Sorry!

Comment: So it does... and a 0 mudulo 11 will never give digit equal to "11".  Nontheless, I prefer adding to alternating subtraction.  I'll take, and I did take the risk with 9 just to add.  Then I had to do 11.  Oh, well.

Comment: So modulo 9 will fail 1 out of 9 times and modulo 11 will never fail. ... yeah, modulo 11 would have been better.  Still modulo 9 was a very god learning experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old trick.

$X = \sum_{i=0}^na_i 10^i = \sum{i=0}^n a_i (9 + 1)^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \mod 9$.

This is why adding up the digits of a number will give you the remainder of the number when dividing by 9[*].

So $172195 \equiv 1+7+2+1+9+5 \equiv 7 \mod 9$

And $572167 \equiv 5+7+2+1+6+7 \equiv 28 \equiv 1 \mod 9$

So $172195*572167 \equiv 1*7 = 7 \mod 9$.

$985242x6565 \equiv 9 + 8 + 5+2+4+2+x+6+5+6+5 = 7+x \mod 9$

So $x + 7 \equiv 7 \mod 9$ so $x \equiv 0 \mod 9$.

So $x = 0$ or $9$.

Bugger.

Okay.  Bigger guns.

$X = \sum_{i=0}^na_i 10^i = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i (11 - 1)^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(-1)^i \mod 11$.

This is why if you add every other digit and subtract every other digit you get the remainder when dividing by $11$[*].

$172195 \equiv 5 -9 + 1 - 2 + 7 - 1 \equiv 1 \mod 11$

$572167 \equiv -5+7-2+1-6+7 \equiv 2 \mod 11$

So $172195*572167 \equiv 2 \mod 11$.

And $985242x6565 \equiv 9-8+5-2+4-2+x-6+5-6+5 \equiv 4 + x \mod 11$

So $x+4 \equiv 2 \mod 11$

$x \equiv -2 \equiv 9 \mod 11$.

As $0 \le x \le 9$ we have $x = 9$.

=====

[*]  well, you get the remainder when you repeat enough times.  Most people know the rule as "a number is divisible by 9 if when you add the digits you get a number that is divisible by 9".  But we can take it a step further and realize even if the number is not divisible by 9, the results will have the same remainder.

Likewise must know the rule of "a number is divisible by 11 if the sum of the odd digits equal the sum of the even digits" (although they *should* include the possibility of being different by a multiple of 11).

Comment: How did you do the second to last line?

Comment: $x + 4 \equiv 2 \mod 11$.  $x \equiv -2 \mod 11$.  $x \equiv -2 + 11 = 9 \mod 11$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** any natural number $n$ is congruent to the alternating sum of its digits modulo $11$.

Example: $172195 \equiv 5 - 9 + 1 - 2 + 7 - 1 \mod 11$.

This happens because $10^k \equiv \pm 1 \mod 11$, where the sign depends on whether $k$ is odd or even.

Comment: 985242x6565=4+x mod 11
So 11 divides 985242x6561-x
Where do I go from here?

Comment: 985242x6565=4+x mod 11.  172195 = 1 mod 11 and 572167 = 2 mod 11.  So 172195$*$572167 = 1 mod 11 $*$ 2 mod 11 = 2 mod 11 = 985242x6565 mod 11 = 4 + x mod 11.  So 2 = x + 4 mod 11.  What number from 0 to 9 will satisfy that?

Answer (score 0):

we use congruence modulo 9.
if a=b (9)  and c=d (9) then
ac=bd (9)
what we call the proof by 9.

Comment: Unfortunately if the final result is 0, as is the case this time, the final digit can be either 0 or 9 and we don't know which without another method.